# Why does Java and C# differ in oops?

Tags: c#, java, oop

1) Why does the following codes differ.

C#:

```cs
class Base
{
  public void foo()
  {
     System.Console.WriteLine("base");
  }
}

class Derived : Base
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Base b = new Base();
    b.foo();
    b = new Derived();
    b.foo();
  }
  public new void foo()
  {
    System.Console.WriteLine("derived");
  }
}
```

Java:

```java
class Base {
  public void foo() {
    System.out.println("Base");
  }  
}

class Derived extends Base {
  public void foo() {
    System.out.println("Derived");
  }

  public static void main(String []s) {
    Base b = new Base();
    b.foo();
    b = new Derived();
    b.foo();
  }
}
```

2) When migrating from one language to another what are the things we need to ensure for smooth transition.

Comment: What is exactly your question? The code is different because it is not the same language. Isn't this answer enough?

Comment: How does this question differ from homework?

Comment: @Filburt: See the answers. That's no homework question

Comment: Clearly Java has more _Oops!_, it was developed earlier. It's any _Uh ohs!_ you should be concerned about.

Comment: @Daniel I didn't say you couldn't give good answers to homework questions.

Comment: @Filburt: What I meant was that the answers show that this is something to "broad" for homework - at least in my opinion.

Comment: @Filburt and all you have to do is look at this dudes profile - I don't think someone with 40 questions and 130 answers is someone at school trying to get homework done - I think it's just someone who phrased their question badly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is that in Java, methods are `virtual` by default. In C#, virtual methods must explicitly be marked as such.
The following C# code is equivalent to the Java code - note the use of `virtual` in the base class and `override` in the derived class:

```
class Base
{
    public virtual void foo()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("base");
    }
}

class Derived
    : Base
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Base b = new Base();
        b.foo();
        b = new Derived();
        b.foo();

    }

    public override void foo()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("derived");
    }
}
```

The C# code you posted hides the method `foo` in the class `Derived`. This is something you normally don't want to do, because it will cause problems with inheritance.

Using the classes you posted, the following code will output different things, although it's always the same instance:

```
Base b = new Derived();
b.foo(); // writes "base"
((Derived)b).foo(); // writes "derived"
```

The fixed code I provided above will output "derived" in both cases.

Answer (score 7):

The C# code will compile with warnings, since you are hiding methods there.

In Java, class-methods are always virtual, whereas in C# they're not, and you have to mark them explicitly as 'virtual'.

In C#, you'll have to do this:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Base");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Derived.");
    }
}
```